# how to monitor java heap memory usage in jboss eap production server

Tags: out-of-memory, jboss-eap-7

I need to monitor java heap memory usage in my production server JBOSS EAP and web server nginx in order to avoid OutofMemory Error. 
Please suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Jboss CLI` to check JVM memory details,

- Connect to the JBoss using CLI:

> `./jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=localhost:9999`

- Getting the JVM Memory details:

> `/core-service=platform-mbean/type=memory/:read-resource(recursive=true,proxies=true,include-runtime=true,include-defaults=true)`

Or you can use `JBoss management console`,

- Go to `Runtime` tab
- Select `JVM` from `Sytem status`

Or you can use `JConsole`

Answer (score 1):

For instructions on how to monitor EAP servers with VisualVM or JConsole, you can see the EAP Performance Tuning Guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/performance_tuning_guide/#monitoring_performance

It also has sections on troubleshooting performance issues, including memory settings.